# What is the verb that describe sand dropping across a face or a wall?

Tags: word-request

What is the verb that describe sand dropping across a face or a wall?

I first looked for dripping but it seemed that dripped is only used for liquids.

Comment: Would you add an example of the type of sentence you would like to use the word in?

Answer (score 1):

Sand can [**flow**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flow) through an hourglass—as well as across a face or down a wall.

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **1 a (1)** : to issue or move in a stream
>   // rivers *flow* into the sea
>   **1 a (2)** : CIRCULATE
>   **1 b** : to move with a continual change of place among the constituent particles
>   // molasses *flows* slowly
>   // water *flowing* over the dam

Although sand, unlike the example sentences, is made up of dry particles, *flow* is still appropriate.

Note that sand can also [**pour**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pour) across a face or down a wall, but it's likely you want the movement to be slower than that verb expresses.

Comment: Trickle might also work for sand